# Chicago Manual of Style 17th edition (full note). Why comma for first author and not the others

Tags: commas, citation, research

My citation management software does this automatically and apparently it's what supposed to be done. There is a comma between the last name and the first name of the first author, but no commas between the last name and the first name of the other authors. This seems very odd. Any idea why this is the case?

[This page discussing Chicago full note citations](https://citationsy.com/styles/chicago-fullnote-bibliography) contains an example:

> So if we want to reference this scientific article: “Testing consumer preferences for iced-coffee: Does the drinking environment have any influence?” by C. Petit and J.M. Sieffermann in Chicago Manual of Style 17th edition (full note):
>
> Petit, C., and J.M. Sieffermann. “Testing Consumer Preferences for Iced-Coffee: Does the Drinking Environment Have Any Influence?” 18, no. 1 (January 1, 2007): 161-72. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodqual.2006.05.008.

Comment: 1. The style one particular reference uses for citations has nothing to do with the English language, much less the thought processes of its originators. 2. Please never post screenshots of text. This discriminates against people with visual deficiencies, and cannot be indexed.

Comment: Nothing to do with the English language. See my separate comment.

Comment: In fact the screenshot is difficult to read at full size, let alone squashed into a column here. Please don't use screenshots: please bother to type out what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. In the case of this particular style, it's so the references can be alphabetized by the first listed author's last name.

Also, it's abundantly common across all styles, even informal, to use a comma when writing names as Last, First and to not use a comma when writing names as First Last. The crux of the question asked here appears to have less to do with why a comma is used and more to do with why the first listed author's name is written Last, First while other offers are written First Last. The reason the first listed author's name is written as Last, First is, as said above, to support alphabetization of the references by first listed author's last name.

Comment: That's crystal clear, thank you very much!